# Linux Mint 21.1 and W10 22H2 installed on separate SSD's

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot

The SSD on which Mint was to be installed was connected by itself.
This SSD was removed form the PC.
The SSD on which W10 Pro was to be installed was then connected by itself.
In each case the OS's booted correctly.

I then installed both drives in the PC with the Mint being primary.
BIOS was edited to boot Mint 1st and all went as expected. Booted successfully into Mint.
Next I used the F10 key to get to the boot menu so that I could manually select the drive on which W10 was installed. Boot was successful into W10.

Now here is the problem; on reboot to access Mint there was no menu and only a message approximating that there is no bootable OS.

Using Live Mint Media I managed to fix this.
However, after booting to Windows again I then again left with a un-bootable Mint drive.

Please advise on how to fix this.
I would prefer to have the setup with the Mint Boot Menu including W10 so that I could decide at that point which OS I needed to use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you fix it the first time exactly, please? Are you booting in a pure UEFI mode or mixed?